# How to position text over resizable imageview?

Tags: text, javafx, imageview, scale

It has a stackpane and few childs inside it:

```
public class SlideFromText {

    private StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    private ImageView iv = new ImageView();
    private int lines_count = 0;
    private Group text_group = new Group();

    public SlideFromText(Image img, String t) {

        iv.setImage(img);
        iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv.fitWidthProperty().bind(sp.widthProperty());
        iv.fitHeightProperty().bind(sp.heightProperty());

        sp.setStyle("-fx-border-color : red; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;");
        sp.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        sp.setMinSize(0, 0);
        sp.getChildren().add(iv);
        String lines[] = t.split("\\r?\\n");
        double height = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            Text text = new Text(line);
            text.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            text.setY(height);
            text_group.getChildren().add(text);
            lines_count++;
            height += text.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
            System.out.println("Height: " + height);
        }

        sp.getChildren().add(text_group);
        iv.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
                Node node = sp.getChildren().get(1);
                if (node.getClass() != Group.class) {
                    return;
                }
                Group group_node = (Group) node;
                double scale_x = iv.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / group_node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
                double scale_y = iv.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / group_node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
                double scale = Math.min(scale_x, scale_y);
                group_node.setScaleX(group_node.getScaleX() * scale);
                group_node.setScaleY(group_node.getScaleY() * scale);
                System.out.println("IVB: " + iv.getBoundsInParent());
                System.out.println("GVB: " + group_node.getBoundsInParent());       
            }

        });
    }

    public Pane getPane() {
        return sp;
    }

}
```

I need to have multi-line text inside group. I want to resize my window and keep image aspect ratio and text proportions and position inside image.

In my example I can't set my text on the top of image.

Maybe it has more easy way.

Comment: Do you want the text font to increase when we are re-sizing the Image or just the text wrapping?

Comment: Increase. It increases now, but if i set sp.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER) i cant vertically aling text group...